# Using setxkbmap to disable the menu key

Tags: setxkbmap

On my Debian for Raspberry Pi, the `win` key pops open the desktop's main menu. This blocks all other keyboard input, so I constantly trip over it. How can I disable the menu behavior using `setxkbmap` so that no key ever opens the desktop menu?

It would be ok to just completely disable the `win` key, since I only use the Pi over VNC for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be easier with `xev` and `xmodmap`, which together can identify the key code and then change the behavior directly (without any layers of abstraction):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 ="
```

Now the land mine is defused and I can work without explosions on my desktop.